# SQL. Проверка запроса

Tags: sql

Задание
В этой задаче необходимо рассчитать общий объем продаж для N ведущих компаний. Для этого есть две таблицы
: company и sales.
Структура таблиц  выглядит так, как показано ниже, и содержит 10 миллиардов строк:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Напишите запрос SQL, который показывает 5 компаний с наибольшим объемом продаж

Я сделала так:(мне показалось подозрительно легко, может быть я не права)

```
 SELECT TOP (5)  c.company_name , SUM(s.price)
 FROM company AS c INNER JOIN  sales AS s
 ON c.item_sold = s.item_sold
 GROUP BY c.company_name 
 ORDER BY s.price DESC
```

Comment: Замените `s.price`  в ORDER BY на `SUM(s.price)` - тогда будет правильно.

Comment: @Akina а не будет ли тогда сумма считаться дважды?

Comment: @AntonShchyrov Не, сервер не настолько дурной... если бы автор присвоила полю суммы алиас, я бы использовал его, а не выражение... а можно вообще `ORDER BY 2 DESC`.

Comment: @Akina можно еще ворос?

Comment: Здесь нет ограничения "один вопрос на участника" - создавайте. Вот второй вопрос в одной теме - это не приветствуется.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Приведенный запрос вообще не должен выполняться. Вы сортируете по полю, которое не участвует в группировке. А если бы и выполнялся, что бы это вам дало? Вам нужно выбрать предприятия с максимальным объемом продаж, а вы сортируете по цене отдельного товара.

Задача решается указанием правильной сортировки

```
SELECT
  c.company_name , SUM(s.price) AS total
FROM company AS c INNER JOIN  sales AS s
  ON c.item_sold = s.item_sold
GROUP BY c.company_name
ORDER BY total DESC
```

Comment: *Задача решается при помощи подзапросов* Нафига?

Comment: @Akina устал потому-что